# Google SignIn for the first time - immediate_failed

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I'm using this script to sign in the user to my webapp.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api:client.js"></script>
<script>
  var googleUser = {};
  var startApp = function() {
    gapi.load('auth2', function(){
      auth2 = gapi.auth2.init({
        client_id: '0000000000000-xxxx00000xxxx0000xxxx0000xxxx000.apps.googleusercontent.com',
        cookiepolicy: 'single_host_origin',
        scope: 'profile',
      });
      attachSignin(document.getElementById('login-with-google'));
      attachSignin(document.getElementById('register-with-google'));
    });
  };

  function attachSignin(element) {
    console.log(element.id);
    auth2.attachClickHandler(element, {},
        function(googleUser) {
            onSignIn(googleUser);
        }, 
        function(error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error, undefined, 2));
            if(error['error'] && error['error'] == 'IMMEDIATE_FAILED'){

                auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
                auth2.signIn(
                    {
                        immediate: false
                    }
                );
                console.log('authorize--end');
            } 
        });
  }
</script>
```

After the user clicks on the button I am getting **IMMEDIATE_FAILED**

```
{
  "type": "tokenFailed",
  "idpId": "google",
  "error": "IMMEDIATE_FAILED"
}
```

I saw some posts here on SO saying that if the user has never connected to my webapp, I have to call SignIn for a second time and the result is

```
{
    error: "popup_closed_by_user"
}
```

Seriously, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but clearly I'm doing something very stupid.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error on JS API.

See more
https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/305